# Optimization Problem on files split based on size

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization, maximize

I am facing an optimization problem and I would like to find an algorithm capable of solving it.

**Hyphotesis**: the total sum of files size is at least greater than 15 MB. So total size is [15 MB; +∞]. For simplicity think of infinity as 100 GB,

**Problem**: I have a list of files with size between 3 KB and 4 MB. I have to zip those files and I need to guarantee that the sum of files size before zip them together is between 15 MB and 150 MB.
There is any known algorithm to deal with this problem? In order not to have an algorithm to much costly in terms of computational requirements it is acceptable not to minimize the number of chunks (so each chunk is not mandatory to be as big as possible).

Thanks,
Giuseppe

Comment: So, you just have to create zip files of maximum 150MB from a list of files?

Comment: Perhaps the knapsack problem?

Comment: So far it seems like an exercise for the plus and less or equal operators. What's the optimization angle? What do you want to maximize?

Comment: @dratenik I would like to maximize the size of each zip file.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 yes, that is the problem.

Comment: With the upper-bound only this is a well-known problem: Bin Packing (with a bin-size of 150MB). If you got the lower-bound as proxy to minimize bins: drop it and use the heuristics / approximations linked at wiki for bin-packing! If it's needed for other good reasons (together with max) you might be in trouble: this could be NP-hard (subset-sum, partition), although i'm not sure. Practically, if there are both, min- and max-bounds: use integer-programming!

Comment: Why do not you just create `zip` file using `zip4jvm` and set split size to `150MB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can tweak the well-known first-fit decreasing algorithm to do this.

```
import random

K = 1000
B = 1
KB = K * B
MB = K * KB


class File:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = random.randrange(3 * KB, 4 * MB)


class Chunk:
    def __init__(self, max_chunk_size):
        self.free = max_chunk_size
        self.files = []

    def add(self, file):
        if self.free < file.size:
            return False
        self.free -= file.size
        self.files.append(file)
        return True

    def enlarge(self, delta_free):
        assert delta_free >= 0
        self.free += delta_free

    def size(self):
        return sum(file.size for file in self.files)


def first_fit_decreasing(files, min_chunk_size, max_chunk_size):
    chunks = []
    for file in sorted(files, key=lambda file: file.size, reverse=True):
        for existing_chunk in chunks:
            if existing_chunk.add(file):
                break
        else:
            if len(chunks) >= 2:
                chunks[-2].enlarge(min_chunk_size)
            new_chunk = Chunk(max_chunk_size - min_chunk_size)
            new_chunk.add(file)
            chunks.append(new_chunk)
    if chunks[-1].size() < min_chunk_size:
        chunks[-2].enlarge(min_chunk_size)
        for file in chunks[-1].files:
            chunks[-2].add(file)
        del chunks[-1]
    return chunks


def test(n):
    files = [File() for i in range(n)]
    min_chunk_size = 15 * MB
    max_chunk_size = 150 * MB
    chunks = first_fit_decreasing(files, min_chunk_size, max_chunk_size)
    assert sorted(id(file) for file in files) == sorted(
        id(file) for chunk in chunks for file in chunk.files
    )
    for chunk in chunks:
        assert min_chunk_size <= chunk.size() <= max_chunk_size
    print(len(chunks), "chunks")
    print(sum(chunk.free for chunk in chunks) / MB, "MB free")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for t in range(1000):
        test(150)
    test(10000)
```